# C# - InstallUtil 32bit installs service but throws error on startup

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I've been working on a Windows Service off and on for some time now and I have finally finished it. On my local machine (Win7, 64bit, .NET 4.5, VS 2013), I've been able to successfully install and run the service which takes info from a website and places it in a SQL table.

Now I want to install this service on a different computer on the network, and it has to be this computer because I've been told to do it like this.

The other computer is running 64 bit Windows Server 2003 R2.

My problems arise when I try to install the service. I'm using plain old command prompt because I do not have the VS command prompt. The code is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe C:\MyService.exe
```

Doing this gives me the error "Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '*filepath*' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.."

So I tried doing this instead:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe C:\MyService.exe
```

Using this 32 bit InstallUtil.exe seemed to work as the service would install successfully and it showed up in my services.msc list. When I try to start the service I then get this error message: "Could not start the service on Local Computer. Error 193: 0xc1"

I'm getting really frustrated/confused with this, so any help what-so-ever would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks for reading.

<---------------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------->

I've changed the configuration to Release and Any CPU, copied and pasted it to the server via Network Folder and installed it once again. Still getting the same error.

<---------------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------->

The answer is in my post below if anyone is wondering, or are having the same issue I was.

Comment: Check that the path to the .exe is correct in the properties for the service.

Comment: I have and it appears correct

Comment: Try removing the service and then use sc instead 

sc create MyService binPath= "C:\MyService.exe"

Comment: Still getting the same error. Error 193: 0xc1

Comment: It looks like one of the DLLs required by your application may not be present...

Comment: Error 193 is ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT.  Pretty hard to guess how you did that.  "Or one of its dependencies" would be a lead of sorts, a 64-bit process trying to load a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: @HansPassant I've done a bit more research into what you were saying and I've checked it out and I do indeed have the sysWOW64 folder on the server so now I'm even more at a loss lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I've figured it out. Where I was using Windows Server 2003, it tends to like the .NET 4 Framework and where the service was developed in Visual Studio 2013 it defaults to the .NET 4.5 Framework. All I had to do, along with several edits to make the service a bit more efficient, was change the target in the VS project to the .NET 4 Framework and rebuild/reinstall on the server.

It has now started without an issue and is communicating with the SQL server as intended. Big thanks to **Hans Passant** for pointing me in the right direction, I would more than likely still be in the process of figuring this out. So thanks!!